# Separate day and night temperature based on time stamp for graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I'm trying to make a line graph where the x axis is the date and the y axis is temperature, with two lines; one for average day temperature and one for average night temperature. How do I make that separation with my data between day and night when I have the date and time data for ggplot?

```
  Time                     PPFD1   PPFD2 Temp1   RH1 Temp2   RH2 Temp3   RH3 Temp4
      <dttm>              <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1 2020-11-30 13:00:00  429. 0.968    24.7  49.9  23.1  59.0  23.1  58.6  19.8
    2 2020-11-30 14:00:00  736. 452.     22.9  53.5  21.1  57.3  20.6  59.2  16.1
    3 2020-11-30 15:00:00  517. 633.     20.3  63.6  19.4  64.8  20.2  63.2  16.2
    4 2020-11-30 16:00:00  537. 393.     20.1  64.0  19.0  70.9  18.6  67.6  16.1
    5 2020-11-30 17:00:00  408. 355.     22.6  53.8  22.5  52.6  21.4  57.1  16.6
    6 2020-11-30 18:00:00  171. 258.     20.9  65.2  21.0  64.8  20.5  67.1  20.2
```

Comment: hour(data$Time) should get you the hours, then just do a selection on hours with which for example

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593108/680068